# Big garden is incorrect?

Tags: collocations

I answered wrong the following question:

> There is a nice house with a big/large garden.

I chose big. Is it incorrect indeed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think you answered the question wrong. I think both sound just fine. Grammatically, and in terms of common usage, both are correct.

Here is a little bit of reading to give you some information on the minor differences between the two:
[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page24.shtml)

[English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24499/whats-the-difference-between-big-and-large)

Comment: Amusing that the page you link to uses almost the exact same sentence -- "The house has a big/large garden" -- as an example of where either one works just as well. I have no idea what the person who wrote the test thought was the "right" answer.

Comment: The test writer was wrong... terribly wrong.

Comment: Yeah. It did occur to me to write something about the test writer in my answer, but I refrained from it. In the end, we don't actually know what the question was, just what OP gave us. Yeah, I was pretty happy the Beeb backed up my answer with the exact same thing!

Comment: I'd like to know more about the directions and test objectives. For example, if the question asked for someone to pick the more **precise** word, _large_ could be considered the better choice. There is nothing grammatically wrong with _big_, of course, but if the test was designed to help learners pick a better adjective, it might be a _large_ garden, a _tall_ building, a _gigantic_ animal, a _spacious_ field, and a _vast_ galaxy (not a big garden, a big building, a big animal, a big field, and a big galaxy).

Comment: #J.R. The test link is : http://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-3311.php

Comment: Yeah, I think we can chalk that up to the test writer (anonyme) being wrong!

Comment: @J.R. Since a garden can only really be "big" in one sense (covering a large area), I don't think that "big" is even any less precise in this case.

Comment: @David - No argument from me; I was just trying to get into the mind of the test maker. Now that I've seen the test, I'm done with trying to give the test maker the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I would see a _tiny_ difference in meaning, I would buy a house with a big garden to impress others, I would buy a house with a large garden if I enjoy much space in my garden. But since the test only asked whether the sentence was right or wrong without discussing the meaning, both are right.

Answer (score 1):

Both adjectives suggest generally the idea of something above average size but broadly large refers to size and big to importance or significance. Large is used for example with clothes and sizes such as small/medium/large/extra large.

A large house would be one with a lot of rooms - a big house also with a lot of rooms and possibly looking imposing as well.